# Поиск слова без повторяющихся символов с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: массивы, регулярные-выражения, std-regex

Мне необходимо найти в строке слова без повторяющихся символов. Для этого решено было использовать регулярные выражения. Я написал вот такой шаблон, но при этом компилятор ругается, что в нём допущена ошибка:

```
^(?!.*(.).*\1)[1234567890]+$
```

Словами является последовательность цифр. По моей задумке данный шаблон ищет все подстроки любой длины, где ни одна цифра не повторяется

Comment: слова или цифры ?

Comment: `std::regex r(R"(^(?!.*(.).*\1)\d+$)")`